# How to declare a generic protocol property requirement in a protocol

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

Struggling for a while with, it will be really helpful if you can shed some light on this:

I have an `APIWorkerProtocol` which has a property requirement, the required property is a protocol i.e `DataParserProtocol`

```
protocol APIWorkerProtocol {
    var apiRequestProvider : APIRequestGeneratorProtocol {get}
    var dataParser : DataParserProtocol{get}
    func callAPI(completionHandler: @escaping (APICallResult<Self.ResultType>) -> Void)
}

protocol DataParserProtocol {
    associatedtype ExpectedRawDataType
    associatedtype ResultType
    func parseFetchedData(fetchedData : ExpectedRawDataType) -> APICallResult<ResultType>
}
```

How can I achieve this?

In this current implementation, this causes an error `Protocol 'DataParserProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`.

Thanks in advance

Ankit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a protocol make use of `Self` or associated type requirements (a homogenous protocol), we may note use the protocol as a concrete type.

So instead of using the `DataParserProtocol` as the concrete type of the `dataParser` property (blueprinted in the `APIWorkerProtocol`), you could add an `associatedtype` typeholder, say `DataParser`, to the `APIWorkerProtocol`, which *is constrained to types that conform to* the `DataParserProtocol`.

Also, I'm not sure what the intent with using `Self.ResultType` as specialization in the completion handler of `callAPI(...)` is (since `Self` would refer to the type implementing the `APIWorkerProtocol`; a protocol which blueprints no `associatedtype` `ResultType`): did you mean to use the `ResultType` of the `DataParserProtocol` type?

E.g.

```
protocol APIWorkerProtocol {
    associatedtype DataParser: DataParserProtocol
    var dataParser : DataParser { get }
    func callAPI(completionHandler: @escaping (APICallResult<DataParser.ResultType>) -> Void)
}

protocol DataParserProtocol {
    associatedtype ExpectedRawDataType
    associatedtype ResultType
    func parseFetchedData(fetchedData: ExpectedRawDataType) -> APICallResult<ResultType>
}
```