# How can assing generic (associated type require) protocol as delegate to any controller?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have a protocol that have associatedtype named MessageType.

```
protocol MessageProtocol: class {
    associatedtype MessageType

    func sendMessage(_ with: MessageType)
}
```

Then implemented it in the controller

```
extension MainController: MessageProtocol{

    typealias MessageType = String

    func sendMessage(_ with: MessageType) {
        // sending message
    }
}
```

My purpose is using the protocol as delegate in other controller like below.

```
final class AnotherController {

    weak var messagerDelegate: MessageProtocol?

    ...
}
```

But I get error of that

> Protocol 'MessageProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint
>   because it has Self or associated type requirements

Is there any way to handle this error?

I've reading Big Nerd Ranch blog post about this situation.
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/why-associated-type-requirements-become-generic-constraints/

I've learned about the situation but no idea about how it can be achived?

Thanks,

Comment: There's no silver bullet. I recommend you read https://robnapier.net/start-with-a-protocol

Comment: @Alexander Thanks, I am reading it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare a generic protocol property requirement in a protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45368824/how-to-declare-a-generic-protocol-property-requirement-in-a-protocol)

Comment: @ThanhVu I read the question and answer but can't figured out how to apply in myself. It can be tagged as duplicate by the way.

Comment: How can `AnotherController` call `messagerDelegate.sendMessage`? It would have to know `MessageType` in order to pass the parameter. So the deep question is "What does your calling code look like?" What in `AnotherController` actually *calls* `sendMessage`? With that, we can work out what the correct types here would be. I suspect the answer is just a function rather than a protocol.

Comment: Hey, @RobNapier,  in sendMessage function there is just print function that print the value. `AnotherController` call delegate because it had generated with MessageProtocol comfortable `MainController` type. It's too absurd, I know. And also `AnotherController` know the `MessageType` because of `T.MessageType == String`. I think the simple and `non-generic` function must be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I handle the situation like that.

```
final class AnotherController<T: MessageProtocol> where T.MessageType == String {

    weak var messagerDelegate: T?

    ...
}
```

And if I want to create anotherController instance programmatically, I created like that.

```
let instance = AnotherController<MainController>(frame: CGRect.zero)
instance.delegate = self
...
```

Because of `MainController` is comfortable with `MessageProtocol` from

`extension MainController: MessageProtocol{}`

Probably it's not common case but worked for me.